# OutputCache controller attribute vary by user role? Is this possible in .net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to output cache controller actions differently based on user role? or if they are authenticated or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at VaryByCustom.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.getvarybycustomstring.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that got me to this, which is working perfect:  

http://codebetter.com/blogs/darrell.norton/archive/2004/05/04/12724.aspx

Answer (score 4):

**[Careful: This answer was valid as of 2011]**

We add the OutputCache directive like this:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="SessionID" %>
```

In MVC, add this attribute to your action

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam="None", VaryByCustom="SessionID")]
```

Then, in the Global.asax file

```
Public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
  if(arg.ToLower() == "sessionid") 
  { 
    HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"]; 
    if(cookie != null) 
      return cookie.Value; 
  } 
  return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

Comment: You can get the session cookie name using the [SessionStateSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection(v=vs.110).aspx) (so that you avoid hardcoding the default cookie name). Also, you should do a case insensitive comparison on the argument, it just looks better. You can check my version of this in this blog post: http://blog.danielcorreia.net/asp-net-mvc-vary-by-current-user/