# C# What should be key to cache results for different Hashsets

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am coding an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. The Navigation menu is created dynamically from DB based on permission set for user, using a child action. Users are allocated to Usergroups/Roles, but then they can also have some certain specific additional permissions. I am having a Hashset being returned by Authorization Services for all the privileges for current user. Most of users would have same privileges as the usergroup (no additional privileges). So, i want to cache the navigation menu.

Questions, 
1. I need to use VaryByCustom option for OutputCache attribute?
2. How should i create unique keys for hashtables having same set of permissions (may be added to hashset in different order)?

Answer (score 1):

**1. I need to use VaryByCustom option for OutputCache attribute?**

I suppose that's the best version. See [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933868/11963) or [in this blog](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/10/29/VaryByCustom-Caching-By-User.aspx).

**2. How should i create unique keys for hashtables having same set of permissions (may be added to hashset in different order)?**

To build the cache key, I have used something similar to this in the past (uses [a GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/11963) implementation):

```
public class Permission
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return this.Id.GetHashCode(); }
}

public static string BuildCacheKey(HashSet<Permission> permissions)
{
    var hashCode = GetHashCode(permissions);
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "permission_{0}", hashCode);
}

private static int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<Permission> permissions)
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hash = 17;
        foreach (var permission in permissions.OrderBy(p => p.Id))
        {
            hash = hash * 23 + permission.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

This should work with several permissions IMHO. If you only have a few permission combinations and not too complicated permission names, you could also just concat the names.

```
public static string BuildCacheKey(HashSet<Permission> permissions)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder("permission_");
    foreach (var permission in permissions.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
    {
        builder.Append(permission.Name);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, i can sort/reorder. Hashset is still a set of privilege objects, how do i generate the cache key - Hashcode?

Comment: @EagerToLearn I think that strategy could depend on how many privileges a normal user has (in total). A few or a few hundred?